# My threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

Trying to do simple programm that uses threads. But I can't understand some things. Here is my code:

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
 import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new BIGBUTTON();

}}

class GUILCLASS extends Thread {
int i;
public GUILCLASS(){
    start();
    i=0;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    super.run();
    while (true){
        System.out.println("I did this cycle " +i +" times");
        i++;
        try {
            sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }
    }
 }
 }
   class BIGBUTTON extends JFrame {
private JButton buttonForTestingButton;
private JPanel panel1;
GUILCLASS guilclass=new GUILCLASS();
boolean mark1;

public BIGBUTTON() {
    panel1=new JPanel();
    buttonForTestingButton=new JButton("Button for testing");
    mark1=true;
    setVisible(true);
    setBounds(100,100,100,100);
    add(panel1);
    add(buttonForTestingButton);
    buttonForTestingButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mouseClicked(e);
            if(mark1){
                synchronized (guilclass){
                    try {
                        guilclass.wait();
                        mark1=false;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();  
                    }
                }
            } else {
                synchronized (guilclass){
                    guilclass.notify();
                    mark1=true;
                }
            }
        }
    });
     }
  }
```

What I'am trying to do is by clicking on button make one thread to wait() untill I click again on this button, but my button just freezing and nothing else happens. Looking for help.

Comment: You may be hogging the Event Dispatch Thread, which causes the GUI to hang. Take a look at its [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). "_Tasks on the event dispatch thread must finish quickly; if they don't, unhandled events back up and the user interface becomes unresponsive._"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to read about how `wait()` works, because it lets sleep the Thread where you execute it.

Basically if you want your guilclass to sleep you would have to call `wait()` somewhere inside the `run()` method. The easiest for you would be to introduce a `static Object` on which you `wait()` inside the Thread `guilclass` until notified if a `static boolean sleep` is set.
The `static boolean sleep` would have to be set when the button is pressed.